# findViewById() returns null for a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have seen couple of examples online, but I still have some problems sending the data to the `ListView`.

This is the `HashMap` created with JSON data:

```
HashMap<String, String> googleRestaurantAPI = new HashMap<String, String>();
googleRestaurantAPI.put("place_name", placeName);
googleRestaurantAPI.put("vicinity", address);
```

This is my `Adapter`:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.foodapp.foodapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList mData;

    public MyAdapter(Map<String, String>map){
        mData = new ArrayList();
        mData.addAll(map.values());
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mData.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position){
        return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;
        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }

        Map.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(item.getKey());
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(item.getValue());
        return result;
    }
}
```

In my layout XML, I have:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The main code:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(googleRestaurantAPI);                
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I set the `Adapter`, it shows an error that the `ListView` is null, even though it is printing the data from the JSON. What could be the problem?

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapte‌​r)' on a null object reference" This means `mListView` is null.  You haven't initialized it with `mListView = `.

Comment: I did. mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapte‌​‌​r)' on a null object reference
```

This means `mListView` is null. You haven't initialized `mListView` properly.

> I did. `mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);`

That doesn't match your XML.  Either change:

- `android:id="@android:id/list"` to `android:id="@+id/list"` (Recommended)
- Or `findViewById(R.id.list)` to `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` (Not recommended)

Comment: Fixed that problem, now it's a problem with the MapEntry on the getItem and getView. "                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry"

Comment: "Fixed that problem" Please click the check mark next to my answer as it solved your question.  You'll have to ask a new question for your new question.  However the error a `String cannot be cast to Map Entry` is self explanatory, which a quick search on Google and a little focus you'll never need to ask for help on a ClassCastException. They are easy to solve, especially since the IDE informs you exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks sam.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` and `HashMap` are different types. You can try it

```
public MyAdapter(HashMap<String, String>map){
    mData = new ArrayList();
    mData.addAll(map.values());
}
```

and

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mData;
```

Comment: Is not working, still the same. The error is:                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference